# Attempted to read or write protected memory. Only when using WCF? Awesomium/HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, wcf, html-agility-pack, awesomium

I have a form that scrapes data from a website, using Awesomium as the browser and HTMLAgilityPack to pass the Html, and sends it to another process using WCF.

When I call the method ScraperForm.GetData() with the button on the form I get no error (the html is grabbed properly by the javascript).

When I call it from my other form (using the WCF client) I get the following error in my ScraperForm:

```
public partial class ScraperForm : Form
{
    public string Html;
    public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HtmlDoc;

    ServiceHost Host;
    ModelDataServer DataServer;

    public ScraperForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        #region Start Data Server
        DataServer = new ModelDataServer();
        DataServer._GetData = new ModelDataServer.GetData(this.GetData);

        Host = new ServiceHost(DataServer, new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri("http://localhost:8000")
            });

        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IModelData),
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            "ModelData");

        Host.Open();

        #endregion

        HtmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        Html = "";
    }

    private void CloseSever()
    {
        Host.Close();
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        #region HTMLScrape - HTML Agility Pack

        // navigate to website
        ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
        Html = webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.documentElement.outerHTML").ToString();
        // *********** Breaks on the line above this! ***********

    // Grab data out from html, add to ret (ArrayList) 

    return ret;        
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();   // Causes No Errors!
    }
}
```

My WCF Interprocess communication code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IModelData
{
    [OperationContract]
    ArrayList GetData();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ModelDataClient
{
    ChannelFactory<IModelData> HttpFactory;
    IModelData HttpProxy;

    public ModelDataClient()
    {
        HttpFactory = new ChannelFactory<IModelData>(
            new BasicHttpBinding(),
            new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8000/ModelData"));

        HttpProxy = HttpFactory.CreateChannel();
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return HttpProxy.GetData();
    }
}

[ServiceBehavior(UseSynchronizationContext = false, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class ModelDataServer : IModelData
{
    public delegate ArrayList GetData();
    public GetData _GetData { get; set; }

    public ModelDataServer()
    {
    }

    public ArrayList GetData()
    {
        return _GetData();   // When called here (Using WCF) it causes the error!
    }
}
```

Error (points to Html = webControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.documentElement.outerHTML").ToString();):

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt

I think this is something to do with setting my scraper form to run as administrator or something. Thanks for your help.

Update:

I followed the instructions here: http://jtstroup.net/post/Attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-This-is-often-an-indication-that-other-memory-is-corrupt.aspx (Turning off Data Execution Prevention) and I'm still recieving the same error.

I believe the problem lies with a mis-match between Awesomium and the rest of my program. Something to do with a different version of .net or something.

Another suggestion I found was to build the whole project as x86 but this hasn't worked either.

Does anyone have any suggestions I can try? How can I change my target .net version to that of Awesomium? Will this work?

Comment: What's the relationship between HtmlDoc and webControl? I'm wondering if you need to initialise HtmlDoc _before_ DataServer.

Comment: HtmlDoc is HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDoc (just a library of functions you can use on a html string). WebControl is the web browser (Awesomium) I'm using to grab the HTML.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it would help if you include the exception stack trace.

Comment: I notice that the attributes on ModelDataServer include `UseSynchronizationContext = false`. If the server executes on a thread separate to that of the WebControl you might need to marshal calls from the server to the same thread. Just a guess!

Comment: Had a look at the Awesomium site which notes the WebCore component is not thread safe and calls to it must be made on the same thread that created it. A forum discussion mentions corrupt memory. I don't know how WebCore relates to WebControl but it seems likely that your server needs to do use the form's synchronisation context.

Comment: You can do this by setting `UseSynchronizationContext = true` or by marshalling calls to the form thread. The latter means capturing the form's SynchronizationContext (the ModelDataServer constructor is a good place for that), then wrap the invocation of delegate _GetData in a call to Send/Post on the SynchronizationContext. There's a good explanation of both approaches at [Writing Smart Clients by Using Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294424.aspx) on MSDN. I could write some code for this if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by pulling the HTML from the webform on a timer, then my WCF just calls a method that grabs the data that was updated from the last tick of the timer.

So yes, the problem is likely to be that the WebCore component is not thread safe.

Thanks groverboy!

Comment: Interesting workaround! I presume the timer belongs to the form, and the timer event handler copies HTML from WebControl to the server object. This means data moves from form to WCF on the form thread: no problem there. But I suspect there's a race condition now: WCF may start and finish reading the copied data before the form has finished writing all of it.

Comment: I have a field (an arraylist) called Data, every tick of the timer Data = GetData() is called on the form (gets data from the html). Then my call through WCF to my scraper form just returns Data. No race condition, my data doesn't have to be SUPER up to date. Thanks though.